# Is it necessary to secure the HDD head before shipping a PC?

Tags: hard-drive

I am planning to relocate from one part of the country to another, and as part of the process need to pack up my PC. The PC is relatively large and heavy, but not too old (from year 2012).

Two of the HDDs inside the PC are not of the solid-state type.

The PC will be part of the belongings shipped inside a truck and I could imagine (considering stiff suspensions on trucks, and at least occasionally bumpy roads) that the HDDs inside it would end up taking some bumps and shocks.

Is it necessary to secure the HDD heads somehow before packing the PC?

Comment: If you pack the computer in a box with padding then it shouldn't be a problem.  Of course I personally wouldn't allow anyone to handle my hardware.  Unless the thing is dropped it should be fine, if it is dropped, your HDDs will be the least of your worries.

Comment: Bring the hard drives in your carry-on luggage. I would imagine they would be fine when going through customs because I am 99% sure that they allow you carry laptops without an issue. If possible then backup your data to a cloud service to guarantee it's safety upon arrival to your destination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to do anything but a normal power-down. Anyway, there's nothing else that you *can* do: I haven't seen a drive that had any means available for "securing the head" in many decades. (That was not a drive that could be put in a PC.)

Comment: This is correct.  Whereas if you pulled the plug while the computer was running, then proceeded to move the computer, you would likely cause damage to the drive.

Comment: It's possible, but I wouldn't call it likely. The heads retract very quickly to the "landing zone" even if you just pull the plug. (n.b.: I am NOT saying that "just pulling the plug" is a good idea!)